The Python C API does not see the Image from the PIL
I have some C++ project that calls the python qrcode library.
auto pil_module = importModule("qrcode.image.styledpil");
auto pil_class = PyObject_GetAttrString(pil_module, pil_module_name.c_str());
if (!pil_class) {
    auto error = PyErr_GetRaisedException();
    std::string msg(u8"Error receiving the class ");
    msg += pil_module_name;
    exception(error, msg);
}
auto drawer_module = importModule("qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil");
auto drawer = PyObject_GetAttrString(drawer_module, module_drawer_name.c_str());
if (!drawer) {
    auto error = PyErr_GetRaisedException();
    std::string msg(u8"Error receiving the class ");
    msg += module_drawer_name;
    exception(error, msg);
}
auto drawer_obj = PyObject_Call(drawer, PyTuple_New(0), nullptr);
if (!drawer_obj) {
    auto error = PyErr_GetRaisedException();
    std::string msg(u8"Error receiving the class ");
    msg += module_drawer_name;
    exception(error, msg);
}

auto make_image_method = PyObject_GetAttrString(qrcode, "make_image");
auto drawer_arg = Py_BuildValue("{s:O,s:O}", "module_drawer", drawer_obj, "image_factory", pil_class);
auto image = PyObject_Call(make_image_method, PyTuple_New(0), drawer_arg);

This piece of code creates arguments and calls the make_image method. At the moment of the call, an error occurs and I catch an exception
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Resampling'

If I run the same python code on the same computer
from qrcode.main import QRCode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil import CircleModuleDrawer

qr_test = QRCode()
qr_test.add_data("Hello, World!")
a = qr_test.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=CircleModuleDrawer())

He's doing a great job
I have pillow version 10.3.0 installed
venv is not used when running programs
in CMake, I have these Python search strings
find_package(Python3 3.12 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
if (Python3_FOUND)
    message("Python include directory: " ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message("Python version is: " ${Python3_VERSION})
    include_directories(${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
endif (Python3_FOUND)

there is an Image import method in the qrcode library, as I understand it, it does not work in my C++ project, but I cannot understand why
# Try to import PIL in either of the two ways it can be installed.
Image = None
ImageDraw = None

try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw  # type: ignore  # noqa: F401
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    try:
        import Image  # type: ignore  # noqa: F401
        import ImageDraw  # type: ignore  # noqa: F401
    except ImportError:
        pass

it is PIL.Image that should have the Resampling property
Thanks for the help
I reinstalled pillow, python, but nothing has changed
I tried to get an Image in C++
PyObject_GetAttrString(pil_module, "Image");

but I got NULL
If I call
PyObject_GetAttrString(qrcode_compat_pil_module, "Image")

I get None

[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve)).
